# What are the risks in disable MySQL old passwords?

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, php-5.2

I am in the following scenario:

- I have to develop a new project in PHP 5.4
- The company has several other [important] systems running on PHP 5.2, VB6 and VB.net, using the mysql old password format *(16-byte passwords)* to connect
- With PHP 5.4, I can't connect to MySQL because the old password error, unless I set the password to the new format *(41-byte passwords)* with:

> SET SESSION old_passwords = 0;

and

> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('my_old_password')

If I make these changes in mysql (setting passwords to the new format), will the systems in PHP 5.2 and VB continue to connect without problems?

Comment: Sorry for possible typos in my question. I am Brazilian.

Comment: I would recommend having a separate user account for your new project.  I always use separate accounts anyway, so that it is easy to disable one should it become compromised.  Your new account can use the new password format, with the old account on the old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(This question is so old and unpopular, but I really need to answer it for the sake of completeness)*

After reading many (really, many) articles on the Internet, there are no documented info about old systems using PHP 5.2 being able to connect with the new password format.

**But**, if I remember well, my final solution was to **upgrade the PHP version** running in those important systems.